# VS for Mac 2019 - tests won't run

Tags: xunit, visual-studio-mac

Set up a toy project in Visual Studio for Mac 2019 to try it out.
I created a new xUnit project with a single test...

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Assert.True(true);
    }
}
```

When i try to run this test I get the following error:

```
Running LMS.LMS.Tests.LMS.Tests.UnitTest1.Test1 ...
Result message:
One or more errors occurred. (vstest.console failed to connect.) 
(vstest.console failed to connect.)
```

I installed nuget package xunit.runner.console but no change.

Has anyone any thoughts for this issue?

Comment: What does the xUnit project file look like?

Comment: Is there a more detailed error in the IDE log file? Help - Open Log Directory.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue myself tonight. Some documentation from Microsoft on using xUnit with Visual Studio for Mac sure would be nice.

Install the following NuGet packages:

- xunit
- xunit.runner.visualstudio

Tests were visible in the Unit Tests debug pad immediately after the packages finished installing and I built the solution - unlike NUnit, where it seems I have to quit Visual Studio for Mac and reopen the solution.

My tests project was a .NET Framework 4.7 class library. Results may be different for other versions (e.g.: .NET Core).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this as well today. But for me everything worked until now. After restarting the machine everything works fine again :)